# Using knitr markdown in RStudio calling two different versions of R (2.15.3 and 3.0.2)

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, rstudio

I would like to be able to create a Knitr Markdown document
calling different versions of R (2.15.3 and 3.0.2) from within R studio.Is this possible?
The reason for this is that some packages that have been discontinued may only 
work in an older version of R

For example:

````
Title
========================================================

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
I would like to run a package from
R version 2.15.3 (2013-03-01) -- "Security Blanket"
here:
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

```{r}
summary(cars)
```

embed plots:

```{r fig.width=7, fig.height=6}
plot(cars)
```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
I would like to run a package from
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25) -- "Frisbee Sailing"

here:
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

``{r}
summary(cars)
```

 embed plots:

 ```{r fig.width=7, fig.height=6}
 plot(cars)
````

---

I added my output here as too large for the comment box
Rscript,exe is in:
C:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.3\bin

```{r,engine='Rscript', engine.path='C/Program Files/R/R-2.15.3/bin/Rscript'}
version

```

on running KNIT HTML I get the following error

Error in system(cmd, intern = TRUE) : 
  '"C/Program Files/R/R-2.15.3/bin/Rscript"' not found

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `engine` tag:

````
```{r,engine='Rscript', engine.path='PATH_TO/R/R-3.0.2/bin/Rscript'}
version
```

```{r,engine='Rscript', engine.path='PATH_TO/R/R-2.15.3/bin/Rscript'}
version
```
````

**EDIT** add a picture of the knitr preview:

[image]

Comment: I tried this,but it does not seem to work```{r,engine='Rscript', engine.path='C/Program Files/R/R-2.15.3/bin/Rscript'}



version



```

Comment: @adam.888 I added a preview of the output in my machine

Comment: Unfortunately, when I run the R code, it still will not run the older version and defaults back to the new one